# Line printing in Python

Tags: python, line-numbers

This exercise is from chapter 20 of Zed Shaw's book.

I am trying to understand a behavior of line number.

When I use the following code, the line number from the text file gets printed as 4, which is wrong. It is in the 3rd line.

```
current_line += current_line
```

However, the line number shows correct when I use the following

```
current_line = current_line + 1
```

Can someone kindly explain what is the difference in the above two lines, which looks same to me and why it is making a difference.

Following is the full code:

```
from sys import argv
script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print f.read()

def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline()

current_file = open(input_file)

print "First let's print the whole file:\n"

print_all(current_file)

print "Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape."

rewind(current_file)

print "Let's print three lines:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line += current_line
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

#current_line = current_line + 1
current_line += current_line
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

Comment: Just so you know, I've upvoted and favorited this question because it is an excellent example of a well-formed beginner question. You've described the problem (with expected and actual results), clearly stated your question, and included an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Many beginners (of programming and using Stack Overflow) leave out one or more of these. Please don't stop asking questions this way.

Comment: Thank you so much :) - I will keep these points in mind asking questions going foreward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

current_line += current_line expands out to

```
current_line = current_line + current_line
```

So lets take a look at what you did, by expanding it out (We will ignore the print statements).

```
current_line = 1
current_line = current_line + current_line # (1 + 1 = 2)
#current_line = 2
current_line = current_line + current_line # (2 + 2 = 4)
#current_line = 4
```

I think you meant to use

```
current_line += 1
```

Comment: Thank you Taztingo. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

You're not increasing the value of of `current_line` by a constant factor of 1, instead you're increasing by a *geometric progression*.

`current_line += current_line` assigns the value of `current_line` to be itself `+` itself:

```
current_line = 5
current_line = current_line + current_line
>>> current_line
>>> 10
```

`current_line = current_line + 1` or `current_line += 1` (`+=1` *is syntactic sugar for increasing a value by 1*) increases the value of `current_line` by 1.

```
current_line = 5
current_line = current_line + 1
current_line += 1
>>> current_line
>>> 7
```

Since `current_line` is a **counter** for the line number, `+= 1` should be used in this case.

Comment: Thank you. I am a beginner to programming and I did not know this is how it worked.

Comment: @Sarat Yeeep no worries, keep at it!